# Question about Spivak's chapter 5 problem 3 part 3

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Question:

Find a $\delta$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ for all x satisfying $0<|x-a|<\delta$

Relating equations to the problem;

$$f(x)=x^4+\frac{1}{x} \\a=1, L=2 $$

rewriting the equation as the definition of the limits

$$|x^4+\frac{1}{x}-2|<\epsilon$$ if and only if $$0<|x-1|<\delta$$

As x approaching closer and closer to a $x^4$ approach to 1 and $\frac{1}{x}$ approach to 1 ,realizing it's the addition of limits rewriting the definition as;

$$|x^4+\frac{1}{x}-(1+1)|<\epsilon$$ now I got

$|x^4-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ if $0<|x-a|<\delta_1$ ,and I got $|\frac{1}{x}-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ if $0<|x-a|<\delta_2$

starting with $x^4$ factoring I got

$$|(x-1)(x^3+x^2(1)+1^2(x)+1^3)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

choose $\delta_1=min(1)$ , and I got $0<|x-1|<1$, using triangle inequality $|x|-|1|\le|x-1|<1$, setting $|x|-|1|<1$, and I got $|x|<2$

rewriting the expression $(x^3+x^2(1)+(1^2)(x)+1^3)\le|x^3|+|x^2||1|+|1^2||x|+|1^3|$, sub |x| in the equation I got $|2^3|+|2^2||1|+|1^2||2|+|1^3|=15$, and I just need to choose that $\delta_1= min(1, \frac{\epsilon}{30})$

for the next limit of $\frac{1}{x}$, I know I can choose $\delta_2$ such that

if $$0<|x-1|<\delta_2$$ then $$|\frac{1}{x}-1|<min(\frac{|1|}{2},\frac{\epsilon|1^2|}{4})$$

now choose $\delta=min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ so I got $\delta=min(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{4},\frac{\epsilon}{30})$

but when I looked at the solution it is $\delta=min(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{4}, \frac{\epsilon}{8\times2\times2})$

So it is $\frac{\epsilon}{32}$ rather than $\frac{\epsilon}{30}$, could anyone check my math and see where I did wrong, and furthermore, in his final answer Spivak ignore $\frac{\epsilon}{4}$, and he got $\delta=min(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{32})$, can anyone give an explanation on why that is so? Is it because $\frac{\epsilon}{4}$ is bigger than $\frac{\epsilon}{32}$, and it did not matter since $\frac{\epsilon}{32}$ is closer to 1?

Comment: Did you make a typo in the part "$|x^4-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ if $0<|x-a|<\delta_1$ and $|\frac{1}{x}-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ if $0<|x-a|<\delta_2$"

Comment: I'm not sure quite get what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: you wrote that we got if ... and ... if ... .I couldn't understand what you meant in that part

Comment: interesting, isn't the definition of limit is if $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, that is what I mean to write

Comment: if $\delta=\min(1,\frac12,\frac \epsilon 4,\frac \epsilon {8×2×2}) $ can't we say $\delta=\min(\frac 12,\frac \epsilon {32})$  even then, I think $\delta=\min(\frac 12,\frac \epsilon {11})$ will suffice.

Comment: I think that's what Spivak doing by throwing out $\frac{\epsilon}{4}$ in his final answer, but I don't know why he got $\frac{\epsilon}{32}$ as opposed to $\frac{\epsilon}{30}$ as I did in my work

Comment: @JamesQuinn I think that may be a trivial distinction.  It could be that he said that $|x^3+x^2 + x + 1|< 2^4$ when $x<2$... when I went trough it, I did the $|\frac1x - 1|$ term first and had already restricted $\delta < \frac12$ and carried that along.  So, $|x^3+x^2 + x + 1|< 8.125$ when $x<\frac32$

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to solve this. We can do a bit of simplification at the beginning using the triangle inequality, and end up with simpler factors, as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}
\left|x^4 + \frac{1}{x} - 2\right| &= \left|(x^4 - 1) + \left(\frac{1}{x} - 1\right)\right| \\
&\leq |x^4 - 1| + \left|\frac{1}{x} - 1\right| \\
&= |x-1||x+1||x^2+1| + |x-1|\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|\\
\end{aligned}$$

Now if we constrain $|x-1| < 1/2$, we will have $|x| > 1/2$, so $|1/x| < 2$. We will also have $|x| < 3/2$, so $|x+1| \leq |x|+1 < 5/2$ and $|x^2 + 1| \leq |x^2| + 1 < 9/4 + 1 = 13/4$. Therefore we end up with
$$\left|x^4 + \frac{1}{x} - 2\right| < \frac{5}{2}\cdot\frac{13}{4}|x-1| + 2|x-1| = \frac{81}{8}|x-1|$$
So if we choose $\delta = \min(1/2, 8\epsilon/81)$, then for all $|x-1| < \delta$, we will have
$$\left|x^4 + \frac{1}{x} - 2\right| < \epsilon$$

Comment: This works too.  +1 The bound I found appears to be a bit more inclusive though.  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV Yep, your bound is more generous, but I bet you had to use some calculus to find the supremum of $x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 - 1/x$ :-)  (which, it occurs to me, might not yet be available in Spivak's chapter 5).

Comment: Well, one can simply plot $x^3+x^2+x+1-\frac1x$ to heuristically determine that the supremum on $(1/2,3/2)$ is equal to its value at $x=3/2$.  Else, we need to apply rigor, which calculus can facilitate.

Comment: This solution is closer to the text because it ties to the previous questions. In part (i) of the same problem you are asked about $\lim_{x \to a}{x^4}$ and thus work with $|x^4-a^4|<\epsilon$, then in part (ii) you are asked bout the limit of $\frac{1}{x}$ approaching 1 and thus work with $|\frac{1}{x} - 1|$ . These simply need to be combined in this part (iii) as per the solution from @Bugno

Answer (score 1):

> **We can actually achieve a broader bound for $\delta$ through straightforward analysis.  To that end, we proceed.**

Note that we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x^4+\frac1x-2= (x-1)\left(x^3+x^2+x+1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$

Now, suppose we restrict $x$ such that $0<|x-1|<\frac12$.  Then, $\frac12 <x<\frac32$.  The supremum of $x^3+x^2+x+1-\frac1x$ on $(1/2,3/2)$ is $\frac{179}{24}$.  Hence, $\left|x^4+\frac1x\right
|< \frac{179}{24}|x-1|$

> Therefore, for all $\epsilon>0$, and $\delta =\min\left(\frac12,\frac{24\epsilon}{179}\right)$,
>
> $$\left|x^4+\frac1x-2\right
> |<\epsilon$$
>
> whenever $0<|x-1|<\delta$.

Comment: interesting, in this way, you have a different $\delta$ for the limit than Spivak's solution, so I assume that there is no definite $\delta$ in an epsilon-delta definition, as long as $\delta$ make $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$, then that $\delta$ is acceptable, if so can you look over my $\delta$ to see if I have pick correctly? thank you for your time

Comment: that is correct.  there is not a single rule for delta.  You just need to show that such a delta exists.

Comment: Yes.  Suppose that for $\epsilon>0$, we find a suitable $\delta>0$ that works.  Then, surely, $\frac12 \delta$ would also work.  Note that the $\delta$ you found sufficed.  The one in the development of this post is larger.

Comment: ok this make so much sense now, thank you, I'm not use to dealing with epsilon-delta definition in a rigorous way, :D

Comment: You're welcome James!  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV $|x-1|<1$ doesn't imply $1 < x < 2$, it implies $0 < x < 2$.

Comment: @Bungo Yes, thank you!  I've edited.  Much appreciative. -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Looks good now (+1). Just curious, is there any reason you need to exclude $|x-1| = 0$?

Comment: @Bungo Thanks!  While we need not exclude $x=1$, I was using the definition of the limit.  Inasmuch as the function of interest is defined at $x=1$ and in fact continuous there, then we can and may drop that restriction.  Good point!  -Mark